# One class SVM toy example not understood

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've been playing around with one class SVM. I think I understand the theory behind it (that it attempts to separate the data from the origin). I attempted to run a toy example which the algorithm should fit perfectly; however it seems like I'm missing something since the algorithm doesn't classify all the training examples as non anomalies.
Code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-5, 5, 500), np.linspace(-5, 5, 500))

x = np.array([1, 3, 1, 3, 2])
y = np.array([1, 1, 3, 3, 2])
feature = np.vstack((x, y)).T
clf = svm.OneClassSVM(nu=0.1, kernel="rbf", gamma=0.1)
clf.fit(feature)
y_pred_train = clf.predict(feature)
Z = clf.decision_function(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]) 
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
print(y_pred_train)
print(feature)
plt.title("Novelty Detection")
plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, levels=np.linspace(Z.min(), 0, 7), cmap=plt.cm.PuBu)
a = plt.contour(xx, yy, Z, levels=[0], linewidths=2, colors='darkred')
plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, levels=[0, Z.max()], colors='palevioletred')

b1 = plt.scatter(feature[:, 0], feature[:, 1], c='white', s=40, 
edgecolors='k')

plt.show()
```

the prediction on the training set is [ 1 -1  1  1  1], which does not make sense.

Please advise.

Comment: why does this output incorrect? According to docs (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html#sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.predict) it returns 1 for an inlier and -1 for outlier

Comment: In the above toy example everything in the training set can be separated from the origin therefore everything should be inlier. makes sense?

Comment: What do you mean separated from the origin? So you're saying that only points close to (0,0) should be expected to be outliers?

Comment: The *nu* parameter is also called the contamination rate, e.g. approximatively the fraction of outlier inside the training data to separate form the rest (inliers).

Answer (score 0):

One Class SVM is taking at least one outlier (anomaly) among your dataset. This is why you see one "wrong" label in the predicted labels.